# (ADAL) integration with Android getting "We are unable to issue tokens"

Tags: android, azure, oauth-2.0, adal, azure-ad-msal

"AADSTS50020: We are unable to issue tokens from this api version for a Microsoft account. Please contact the application vendor as they need to use version 2.0 of the protocol to support this."

Comment: HI,Is this native android application ? what about version ? Are you using ADAL library ?

Comment: @MohamedInfaaz, yes it's native android app and i am using ADAL library. Please check below.

implementation('com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.14.+') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

Answer (score 1):

ADAL doesn't support Azure AD v2.0. You can use MSAL library to achieve this.
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android

Comment: Thanks for help @Mohamed Infaaz. I have done using MSAL library and it was working fine.